# How can I programmatically set column filters?

Tags: extjs

I am working on a Ext.js 5 web applications.  I have a Ext.grid.Panel and I have

```
selModel: {
    type: 'spreadsheet'    
  },
```

Here is a screen shot of what I have now:

[image]

I would like to be able to set the filter on the 'Status' column to 'Ready'.  I am not sure what I need to do.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Thanks to DrakeES for pointing me in the right direction.  What I needed to do was add this code ...

```
  1 /*global   */
  2 Ext.define("Requestor.view.main.RequestGrid", {
  3   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',     // Our base class. A grid panel.
...
 42   // Here we define our grid columns based on our associated store and model.
 43   columns: [
...
 72     {
 73       text: 'Status',
 74       dataIndex: 'status',
 75       itemId: 'status',
 76       renderer: function(value, metaData) {
 77 //RED
 78       var filter = this.up('panel').down('#status').filter;
 79       if (!filter.menu) {
 80          filter.createMenu();
 81          filter.menu
 82             .down('menuitem[value="Ready"]')
 83             .setChecked(true);
 84       }
 85 //RED
 86         metaData.tdStyle = (value == 'Ready') ?
 87           'color:green;font-weight: bold' :
 88           'color:red;font-style: italic'
 89         return(value)
 90       },
 91       filter: 'list',
 92       flex: 1,
 93     },
```

Comment: Looks like you've got [`list`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.filters.filter.List) filter applied to the Status column already, so what is the problem with *setting* it by clicking on one of the 4 checkboxes? Or do you need it done programmatically? Or what?

Comment: How can I programmatically set column filters? So, yes, I need it done programmatically.

Comment: Haha, I just didn't see the word *programmatically* in the body of your question — it was in the header only which my radar had missed :)
I'm glad my answer was helpful and that you seem to be happy with your solution. Though look, you are doing the filter check in the column `renderer`. This will be called **for each** row in the grid, you see? I guess you didn't want that. If you need the filter to be set initially right after the grid is rendered then checking the filter in an `afterrender` event handler would be much more appropriate.

Comment: Awesome! thanks again. Yes an afterrender is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Retrieve the column filter. To make this easy, assign an `itemId` to the column config:

```js
{
    dataIndex: 'status',
    text: 'Status',
    itemId: 'status',
    flex: 1,
    filter: 'list'
}
```

2. Initiate its menu if it does not exist yet;
3. Retrieve the relevant checkbox menu item and make it checked.

Code:

```js
var filter = grid.down('#status').filter;
if (!filter.menu) {
    filter.createMenu();
}
filter.menu
    .down('menuitem[value="Ready"]')
    .setChecked(true);
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pn6

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I run the fiddle example the filters and ready  checkboxes are not checked and non-Ready rows are shown.

Comment: OK I got it figured out now, thanks to DrakeES help.  I have update my question with the important details.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I still have a few questions which I put into a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190820/where-to-programmatically-set-column-filters-when-using-a-spreadsheet-selmodel could you please take a look :)